# Typescript -> es6 -> es5 error with sourcemaps

Tags: typescript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

When compiling typescript -> es6 -> es5  appears a problem with sourcemaps.
I'm want to get typescript sourcemaps, but they generated only for files in root directory.
For nested folders generated only es6 sourcemaps, without ts.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPmua.png)

Tools:
gulp-tsb: 1.10.0,
gulp-babel: 6.1.2,
gulp-sourcemaps: ^1.3.0

Options in tsconfig:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
 "rootDir": "src/",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "target": "es6",
 "module": "commonjs",
 "declaration": false,
 "noImplicitAny": false,
 "noResolve": true,
 "removeComments": true,
 "noLib": false,
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true     
}
```

My gulp task:

```
var typescriptCompiler = typescriptCompiler || null;
   gulp.task('build-system', function() {
    if(!typescriptCompiler) {
       typescriptCompiler =  typescript.create(require('../../tsconfig.json').compilerOptions);
}
  return gulp.src(paths.dtsSrc.concat(paths.source))
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
  .pipe(typescriptCompiler())
  .pipe(to5(assign({}, compilerOptions.commonjs())))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just compile TypeScript to ES5?

Comment: async/await. Compile typescript to es5 with async/await will be avaliable at typescript 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few bugs:

> TS > ES6 > JS conversion while preserving source maps from original *.ts files
>
> I created a small repo with the code that shows the error: https://github.com/helios1138/--babel-sourcemaps-error-case
>
> clone, npm install and run ./build.sh to see Invalid mapping error
>
> It looks like changes in TS2.0+ prevent a relative sourceMapUrl from being generated despite the adding the `mapRoot` attribute in the tsconfig.json

**References**

- [TypeScript Issue #10612: Not producing relative sourceMappingUrl's with mapRoot](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10612)
- [Webpack Issue #2995: /* #sourceMappingURL= ... */" in a JS comment triggers a webpack errors](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2995)
- [Babel Issue #3751: impossible to pass inline sourcemaps from typescript through es6 > es5 transpilation ("Invalid mapping" error) (T6686)](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3751)
- [systemJS Issue #450: In-browser transpilation sourcemaps do not work outside of Chrome](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/450)